# Finding both forward and reverse discrete cosine transform using python. please do not use the built in dct and idct from numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Hello guys thanks in advance for your help and assistance?

I am trying to perform both the forward and reverse cosine transform for the equation below in python. But I keep getting this error saying index is out of bounce. I have tried all means to correct this but it is not working. Kindly find below is my written program in python. Your help will make a big difference. thanks

`F_k = .5*[f_0 + ((-1)**k)*f_N] + f_j*cos(pi*j*k/N)    j=[1  N-1]`

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def dct(f_j):
    n = len(f_j)
    F_k = np.zeros(n, dtype=float)
    for k in range(n):
        out = f_j[0]
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            out += 0.5*f_j[1]+0.5*f_j[k+1]*(-1)**(n-1) + f_j[j] * np.cos(np.pi * k * j/n)
            F_k = out

    return F_k

def idct(F_k):
    N = len(F_k)
    f_j = np.zeros(N, dtype=float)
    for j in range(N):
        output = F_k[0]
        for k in range(1, N + 1):
            output += .5*F_k[1]+0.5*F_k[j+1]*(-1)**(N-1) + F_k[k]*np.cos(np.pi * k * j / N)
            f_j = output * (2 / N)

    return f_j
```

Comment: you're first problem is that you've set your index `j` to run from `1` to `n` and then tried to access `f_j[j]` when `f_j` only has valid indices from `0` to `n-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discrete cosine transform has several definitions.  It looks like you're trying for the [DCT-I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) definition from Wikipedia.  If that's the case you want your code to look something like this,

```
def dct( f_j ):
    n = len(f_j)
    F_k = np.zeros(n)
    for k in range(n):
        F_k[k] = 0.5 * ( f_j[0] + (-1)**k * f_j[n-1] )
        for j in range(1, n - 1):
            F_k[k] += f_j[j] * np.cos(np.pi * j * k / (n-1))
    return F_k
```

I think you're just getting confused about the mathematical definition of the DCT and the indexing in Python which starts from `0`.  Also note that `for k in range(n)` will produce values of `k` from `0` to `n-1` while `for j in range(1, n-1)` will produce values of `j` from `1` to `n-2`.

Comment: Hey Gab,thanks a lot for the rectification of the problem in my code. For some reason the reverse dct not happy either. I am very sure I am not doing something right. This time what PyCharm is complaining about is the indexing in the for j in range(n) loop is not valid. Thanks again for your response. 

def idct(F_k):

    N = len(F_k)

    f_j = np.zeros(N, dtype=float)

    for j in range(N):

        f_j[j] = 0.5*(F_k[0] + (-1)**j * F_k[N-1])

        for k in range(1, N - 1):

            f_j[j] += F_k[k] * np.cos(np.pi * j * k / (N-1))

            f_j = f_j[j] * (2 / N)

    return f_j

Comment: you should make `(2/N)` -> `(2./N)` and think about what you want `f_j = f_j[j]` to do